# process php whithout refreshing page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a problem with process to insert database, I have 3 tables and I want to proccess 3 tables alternately. 
example : 
I want to process insert into table A , from data table A continue to table B, and from data table B continue to table C whithout refreshing page, I want use Ajax , is there any script to used?
my script this :

```
<?php 
break;
    case submit :
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_A(id,field1,field2,field3,date) VALUES ('','$field1','$field2','$field3','$datenow')");
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=index.php?mod=process&act=step1'>";
break;
    case step1 :
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_B (id,field1,field2,field3,date) VALUES ('','$field1','$field2','$field3','$datenow')");
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=index.php?mod=process&act=step2'>";
break;
    case step2 :
case step1 :
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_C (id,field1,field2,field3,date) VALUES ('','$field1','$field2','$field3','$datenow')");
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=index.php?mod=process&act=OK'>";
?>
```

Comment: You could use jQuery's ajax module and either chain $.ajax() requests, long poll, or use web sockets.  Whats your real life use case?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go through some documentations and try to do something.

Learn what is ajax and use javascript here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Use jquery for ajax here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Finally switch statement syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp

Comment: thanks,but i have already use ajax, but only just one process , I want three step process alternately. this my ajax :  
 $('#reg-form').submit(function(e){
  
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission
  
    $.ajax({
 url: 'submit.php',
 type: 'POST',
 data: $(this).serialize(), // it will serialize the form data
        dataType: 'html'
    })
    .done(function(data){
     $('#form-content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
          $('#form-content').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
        });
    })
    .fail(function(){
 alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...'); 
    });
});

Comment: Why dont you do all these in single ajax?